# How can I trace a user on my network?

Tags: network

I want to trace a user based on IP Address (or MAC Address) on a Network with about 10 L2 or L3 Switches. Is it possible to know that on exactly which switch and on which port a user with a specific IP Address (or MAC Address) is working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, all you need to do is query all your switches for the mac-address table. From there you can see to which physical switch the user is connected to, all you need to do then is follow the TP-cable to the machine.

Wireless is a bit more complicated as you can only be sure about the access point the user is connected. If you aren't dealing with malicious users (who often spoof mac addresses) you can try to see if the user is using a particular chipset (based on the MAC address you can identify the chip vendor). From here you can establish what type of device it most likely is (it's not foolproof though).